# Same wordpress plugin, multiple local websites

Tags: wordpress, git, github

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

I have a WordPress plugin hosted on GitHub - lets call this plugin 'LK-FORM', and it's running on 3 different live websites. 'LK-FORM' is exactly the same for each website.

These 3 different websites are also running locally using Ampps.

My question is; How do I get 'LK-FORM' to be in 3 local websites but still update the master branch on GitHub when one of them is changed so that all 3 live sites stay up to date.

I've cloned 'LK-FORM' into one local plugin folder, but when I go to clone again, the repo isn't there anymore since it's already listed on the GitHub GUI. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a use case for [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), although a Google search will turn up many articles against their use. Submodules have a lot of gotchas, but you can make good use of aliases or tools like [gitslave](http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/).

Edit: You could also just clone to one directory and symlink the others, adding them to .gitignore to prevent redundancy.

Comment: Okay thanks, i'll take a look at what you've suggested then.